# Start download, check file type, cancel download

Tags: python, url, http-headers, mime-types

I want to check the file type of a file placed on a certain URL. Now I know two ways of doing that:

1. Check the URL file ending (or at least `Location` from a HTTP Request Response)
2. Check the `Content-Type` (MIME type)

From both of these, the first is a lot more unreliable, but also the second does not always guarantee the best results. So I thought, wouldn't it be possible to send a `GET` request and check the file type while the resource is downloaded and then cancel the download?

If I start downloading a file in my browser, I can see the file extension as well. Is this doable in Python?

Comment: Just pass an open connection to your libmagic wrapper library and it should stop reading when it determines the filetype.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file extension of the download, you can check for `Content-Disposition` header. One typical example:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=<downloadFilename>
```

If the response contains the above header, you can use regexp to get the filename, and then take your actions. In case that header is not present you will have to fall back to the methods you have mentioned in your question.

In case you are interested in the file-type of the download, I would suggest stick to MIME-type -- thats more reliable (usually)

HTH

Comment: The Content-disposition parameter is set very seldom.